# How to handle Delivery Status Notification of various Email Providers?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, dsn

I earlier had code that handled gmail's failed delivery status by checking

```
msg.getHeader("X-Failed-Recipients")[0]
```

But this code fails with other email providers like Yahoo, who don't use this Header, to list delivery failures.

Is there a general way, by which I could fail if delivery to an email Address failed or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get the answer out of DeliveryStatus.toString().
The information you're looking for is in the per-recipient delivery status notification
information for the first recipient. Use getRecipientDSN(0), which returns an InternetHeaders
object. Look in that for the header "Diagnostic-Code".

See the javadocs for the com.sun.mail.dsn.DeliveryStatus class for details.

Comment: Is "Diagnostic-Code" a necessary field contained in all DSN messages ?

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1590599 , plz check this link may be it help you